# 3rd and 4th serial port not configured on startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, serial-port

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 3.2.0-39-generic-pae

Hi there, the PC I'm working on has 4 serial ports.

ttyS0 and ttyS1 function properly straight from startup,

ttyS2 and ttyS3 do not.

here is the relevant dmesg messages:

```
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.050346] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.100595] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.144567] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.188577] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.383941] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    1.449179] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.477192] 00:07: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.498296] 00:08: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
[    1.524994] 00:09: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
```

to get them to function I have to re-configure them by invoking:

```
setserial /dev/ttyS3 baud_base 115200 auto_irq skip_test autoconfig
```

which I found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/serial-port-problem-516635/)

Before re-configuring the serial port, setserial reports the following for the serial ports:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 7
```

After re-configuring the fllowing is reported:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 0
```

The serial ports are provided by a fintek f81866 chip which supports IRQ shareing so having the initial IRQs set to 7 should not be a problem. while having the IRQs set to 0 is a problem from what I understand as according to the setserial [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/setserial.8.html) IRQ 0 is reserved for Timer channel 0.

The fintek f81866 chip supports up to 6 serial ports.

So I tried adding `8250.nr_uarts=8` to the bootline but, this did nothing (as far as I know, I don't know of a way to confirm what boot parameters have been passed).

Whats is going wrong?
Why isn't ttyS2 and ttyS3 being configured correctly at startup?

How can I fix this?
What would I need to do so that they are configured correctly at startup (short of making my own init script)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to boot with this configuration applied on the serial port you can modify the

/var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf

to modify the configuration of the ttyS3, including the sentence you used to reconfigure it correctly.

The autoserial.conf file is used on the boot process by /etc/rc0.d/K19setserial script.

Here's my own file

```
/dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x03f8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS1 uart 16550A port 0x02f8 irq 3 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS2 uart 16550A port 0x03e8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
#/dev/ttyS3 uart 16550A port 0x02e8 irq 3 baud_base 115200 spd_normal
/dev/ttyS3 baud_base 115200 auto_irq skip_test autoconfig spd_normal
```

Comment: hey thanks!, I never saw any mention of /var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf when trying to solve this initially, turns out that the cause was the PC manufacturer borking the BIOS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example of `/var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf` for an Advantech UNO-3072A industrial PC

```
/dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x03f8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS1 uart 16550A port 0x02f8 irq 3 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test
/dev/ttyS2 uart 16950 port 0xcc00 irq 18 baud_base 921600 low_latency
/dev/ttyS3 uart 16950 port 0xc880 irq 18 baud_base 921600 low_latency
```