# Autoconfigure PCIe UART Card at boot - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, sudo, serial-port, dosbox

I am trying to configure a Serial PCIe card (Exar XR17V3521 Dual PCIe UART) for use in DOSBox 0.74-3. The card uses the `XR17V35X` kernel module.
Everything works fine, as long as I run `setserial /dev/ttyS4 autoconfigure` after each reboot and run DOSBox with `sudo`...
I need to make it work at boot automatically and to allow non-privileged users to use DOSBox with this port. Can anyone tell me how to `autoconfigure` the UART card at boot via a `.conf` file?

Comment: I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279779/3rd-and-4th-serial-port-not-configured-on-startup) post that answered my question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3rd and 4th serial port not configured on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279779/3rd-and-4th-serial-port-not-configured-on-startup)